# Selecting from a dropdown which then can be used at an WHERE later?

Tags: php, mysql

I am aware this is the old MySQL driver, not [MySQLi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQLi) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php). I am wanting to finish my web site using what I know and then going to ask some lovely person to convert it for me for a price.

I have an entry form. The first dropdown is Select Event which pulls data from the database. Code below:

```
 <td width="490">Select Event:</td>
      <td width="373"><span id="spryselect1">
        <select name="event" id="event">
          <?php
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM skiptonevents ORDER BY id ASC");
            echo "<option value=\"\">Please select one...</option>";
            while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
              echo "<option value=\"" . $result['name'] . "\">" . $result['name'] . "</option>";
            }
            ?>
        </select>
      <span class="selectRequiredMsg">Please select an event.</span></span></td>
```

Once the person has selected which event they want they continue to fill out the remainder of the form with their personal details.

At the bottom of the form there is "Payment: 'dropdown'"

Code:

```
 <tr>
      <td colspan="4" align="center"><select name="amount" id="amount">
          <?php
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM skiptonevents WHERE name = '". $event . "' ");
            echo "<option value=\"\">Please select one...</option>";
            while($result2 = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
              echo "<option value=\"" . $result2['quote'] . "\">" . $result2['quote'] . "</option>";
            }
            ?>
        </select>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
```

As you can see I have added `WHERE '" . $event . "'` which is the dropdown at the tops 'ID'. This does not work. So when the WHERE matches what has been selected at the top it will show the quote from the database for that event.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: is this all in the same script file? Most likely at the point you run the second query, no form has been submitted, so $event won't be set...

Comment: Yes it is. Of course it will not understand what $event is until its been sent. Is there a way of picking up what it is without the form been sent?

Comment: What is "i" in "i or pdo"?

Comment: The `i` in `mysqli` stands for improved and PDO stands for 'PHP Data Object'

Comment: There is not a simple way to do this using just PHP. Your server has rendered the entire page in static HTML and run all your DB queries before the user even gets to pick an event. You have two options here that I can see - the easy option: post the results of the first part of the form to another page containing the second part of the form. The hard option: Have your server return a JSON file containing the relevant data and use JavaScript to populate the form.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have decided to stop building where I am and start over.

Answer (score 1):

The data that comes from the `<form>` is placed in an array for you to use and not ( unless you are using a very old PHP and still have safe_mode turned on) in a variable. And even if it is you should use the arrays or your code will not port to a newer version of PHP

The arrays are $_GET and $_POST, depending on the method attribute you use `<form method="get">` or `<form method="post">`

So assuming your using `method="post"` amend your query like so

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                      FROM skiptonevents 
                      WHERE name = '{$_POST['event']}'");
```

You should really validate/sanitize the `$_POST['event']` before you use it as it came from an untrusted source.

You should also look at changing from using the mysql_ extensions to mysqli_ or PDO as the mysql_ extensions are deprecated and have been removed from PHP7, which is soon to be released.

Comment: Thank-you for your answer. I have decided to stop building the site and going to start over using mysqli.